# How to parse date string in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I tried to learn to parse xml in Clojure using data.zip as in [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/parsing_xml_with_zippers.html).
if I have a date tag like

```
<date>mm/dd/yyyy</date>
```

how do I parse it to a datetime type in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at clj-time library, particularly this part:  [clj-time.format](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time#clj-timeformat)

For example:

```
(def custom-formatter (formatter "yyyyMMdd"))
```

Comment: can you improve this by giving an example? i.e how to format "now"